# Only allow this specific pattern in an input box with words starting with a pound symbol and followed by a single space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to restrict this pattern in an input box using javascript:

> #foo #bar2 #hello3 #world

Each word must start with a pound sign immediately followed by only an alphanumeric string and then a single space separating them.

I can get everything but the single space using:

> /^[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+$/

I'm lost on how to restrict to just a single space after each word.

```
let allowed = /^[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+$/ 
element.on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (!allowed.test(e.key)) return false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`#` and space should not be inside the `[]`, since that allows them to be mixed anywhere among the letters and numbers.

`#` has to be before the character set, and space has to be before additional repetitions of the pattern.

```
let allowed = /^#[a-z0-9]+(\s+#[a-z0-9]+)*$/;
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, but this just returns false on the first character input attempt.

Comment: Of course. You have to type at least 2 characters to match the pattern, since it requires a word after `#`. You shouldn't try to validate the entire input while you're still typing. Do this in a `change` listener rather than `keypress`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I need it to not allow in the input box on keypress.  I may have to do it with a function instead of regex, seems like I hit a barrier here.

Comment: You could change the `+` to `*` so the word after the `#` is optional. But then you'll need something more strict when they're done editing, to make sure they added a word.

Comment: Probably searching for unubtanium on this one .. but I did learn something from your post, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern `#[a-zA-Z0-9]+( #[a-zA-Z0-9]+)* ?` validates the input. The CSS is set to show a green input field on valid input, and a red one on invalid:

```css
input:valid {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<label>Tags:
<input name="tags" pattern="#[a-zA-Z0-9]+( #[a-zA-Z0-9]+)* ?" />
</label>
```

Explanation of regex:

- `#` -- literal hash sign
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -- 1+ alphanum chars
- `( #[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` -- optional additional tags, separated by a space)
- `?` -- optional space at the end (to avoid red when adding a tag)

Notes:

- To disallow a trailing space omit the  `?` at the end
- if used with a JavaScript validation instead of a `pattern""` attribute you need to anchor the regex at the beginning and end: `^#[a-zA-Z0-9]+( #[a-zA-Z0-9]+)* ?$`